# Material UI React: Collapse with inverted direction

Tags: reactjs, animation, material-ui

I want to animate an element when mounting so that it appears from the bottom. My project is using Material UI. MUI has a component called Collapse that seems to be for this purpose, however it only animates from the top or left, and it does not accept a property for reversing the direction. How do I get around this?

Comment: hi did you find solution?

Comment: As of now, I still haven't seen a reverse orientation feature. I had to create my own collapse component with right to left slide. It's a shame Material UI doesn't provide this feature